# How to inject a few lines of code after a a particular position by reading content from a file?

Tags: javascript, java, file-handling, insertion, file-read

Hi I am new to programming. As I am learning, I want to inject a few lines of code after a certain position after reading a file. Say I have a file  **hello.js** I read it and then I need to insert certain codes after a position. Sample code.

```html
function formKeyDown()
    {
  //position where codes must be injected
        if (condition)
        {
          //Some code
        }
    }
```

I tried using **indexOf()** and **getLineNumber()**. But every time index may not be same and line number also may not be same. line may get duplicated at times in **js** file. Please help. How can I do it?

Comment: what exactly d you mean inject code in? Why can't you simply put it there to begin with? And in case theres multiple cases, use if else statements?

Comment: also, if the function/code you want to inject is in an external js file, simply include it in the html file then call the functions here normally.

Comment: Say I am building one website having 10 js files. Everything done. But later I realized a few more lines need to be added. Every time I don't want to open each file and include/inject codes. So on the go I want to add a few lines to each file. That's my requirement @Irtza.QC